# Set default audio device for RDP connection

Tags: audio, remote-desktop

I have two computers (client and server), which are connected by RDP (mstsc.exe). The client computer has two audio devices - speakers and headphones - and only one of them can be default audio device. The problem is RDP connection always use default audio device for redirecting sound from remote server to client. How to force mstsc.exe to use non-default audio device, while all other programs will remain unchanged?

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10 allows you to set audio options on a per-app basis using [this process](https://www.howtogeek.com/352787/how-to-set-per-app-sound-outputs-in-windows-10/):

1. Launch your RDP session
2. Go to **Settings**
3. Select the **System** category
4. Choose **Sound** from the left menu
5. Click **App volume and device preferences** at the bottom of the window
6. Choose the desired output device for the Remote Desktop app

Comment: Tried that, works on most other apps, but not RDP (mstsc.exe)

Comment: Does it show up on your list in that setting window? I found that you had to have an open RDP connection before navigating to the setting.

Comment: Yes, it is visible after opening RDP connection. Audio stream is going only to default device, no matter what I set for RDP. Seems like Windows 10 bug.

Comment: In Windows 10 1909 RDP was removed from this settings screen as it's not supported